# Search nested object and return reference to first found function, unknown size, unknown name

Tags: javascript, node.js

I saw a lot of people asking how to find a object within an object, so I wanted to make a module that can search a JSON object and find if it has a key or that property and return a reference to that property.

So far I have:

- Find if **the key** and or **property** exists

I can not figure out how to search a nested object of unknown size and shape, and if it finds a function for the value of that key, return a reference to it, so it can be called.

```
/*
    @param Object
    @param String, Number, Bool, Type...
    Return a unknown position in an unknown
    nested Object with an unknown size or structure
    a function.
 */
function search(o, q) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        if (o[k] !== null && typeof o[k] === 'object') {
            search(o[k]);
            return;
        }
        /* Need e.g. */
        if (typeof k === 'function' || typeof o[k] === 'function') {
            // If functions object name is four, return reference
            return o[k] // Return function() { console.log('Four') } reference
            // We could use return o[k][0] for absolute reference, for first function
        }
        if (k === q || o[k] === q) {
            (k === q) ? console.log(`Matching Key: ${k}`) : console.log(`Matching Value: ${o[k]}`)
        }
        return o[k];
    });
}

let data = {
    1: 'One',
    'Two': {
        'Three': 'One',
    }, 
    'Four': function() {
        console.log('We successfully referenced a function without knowing it was there or by name!');
    }
};

search(data, 'One');
// I would like to also
let Four = search(data, 'Four'); // We might not know it's four, and want to return first function()
// E.g. Four.Four()
```

But then again, we would not know 'Four' would be the key. That's when we could use a if statement if typeof function for value. But I cannot seem to **return it correctly to execute the function**, especially if we are just returning first function we find without knowing the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a reference and the key as a single object — i.e. the return value of the function would be `{foundKey: someValue}`. Then you can determine if `someValue` is a function you can call it. For example:

```js
function search(o, q) {
  for (k in o) {
      if (k === q) return {[k]: o[k]}  // return key and value as single object
      if (o[k] !== null && typeof o[k] === 'object') {
          let found =  search(o[k], q)
          if (found) return found
      }       
  }
}

let data = {
  1: 'One',
  'Two': {'Three': 'One',}, 
  'Four': function() {
      console.log('We successfully referenced a function without knowing it was there or by name!')
  }
}

let searchKey = "Four"
let found = search(data, searchKey);

console.log("Found Object", found)

// is it a function? if so call it
if (typeof found[searchKey] == 'function'){
  found[searchKey]()
}
```

If you are *just* interested in finding the first function, you can test for that in the boundary case and return it. Then you need to test whether the function returned undefined before trying to call it:

```js
function firstFuntion(o) {
  for (k in o) {
      if (typeof o[k] == 'function') return o[k]
      if (o[k] !== null && typeof o[k] === 'object') {
          let found = firstFuntion(o[k]);
          if (found) return found
      }  
  };
}

let data = {
  1: 'One',
  'Two': {
      'Three': 'One',
  }, 
  'Four': function() {
      console.log('We successfully referenced a function without knowing it was there or by name!');
  }
};

let found = firstFuntion(data);

// firstFuntion should return a function or nothing
if (found) found()
```